# What is printed in Vulcan script on Spock's black robe in 'Star Trek: The Motion Picture'?

Tags: star-trek, languages, costume, star-trek-the-motion-picture

As seen in the following screenshot, running vertically down the center of his suave jacket/coat.

[image: Spock in Robe, from ST:TMP]

I've compared to supposed charts of the Vulcan alphabet. It appears to be three large letters that aren't listed in the chart?

[image: Vulcan–English Alphabet]

Comment: Looking at [Vulcan language](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Vulcan_language) and seeing Spock's burial robe led me to [this tumblr](http://vulcanlanguage.tumblr.com/post/38233121568/vulcan-robes-rata-tafar-and-tapan) which  mentions the script is `rata, tafar and tapan`, meaning `concept, mental discipline and cerebral process`. I'm not well versed in Star Trek so hopefully this could help someone form an answer

Comment: What an absurdly difficult-to-read script

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - As an American, I could say the same about Tibetan or Chinese, and I'm sure that there are Chinese or Tibetans who would say the same about the Latin alphabet as used for English.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Chinese symbols are far more complicated than Latin ones because they are *logograms*, referring to entire words--not *letters* referring to sounds or parts of sounds. The Vulcan script results in words with as many symbols as English where each symbol is more complex and intricate than an entire word in Chinese. I rest my case.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - Tibetan is closer to Vulcan than it is to Chinese, structurally. And I could have substituted Arabic (alphabetic/abjad), Japanese kana (syllabary), or Korean hangul (alphabetic) and still made the same statement. "Absurdly difficult to read" is a value judgement that is dependent on where you're starting from.

Comment: It says, "Kiss me, I'm Vulcan".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this](http://vulcanlanguage.tumblr.com/post/38233121568/vulcan-robes-rata-tafar-and-tapan) Tumblr posting, it's claimed that the characters don't translate as letters but rather as words, specifically *Rata*, *Tafar*, *Tapan*, meaning "Concept, Mental Discipline, Cerebral Process".

[image: Rata, Tafar, Tapan characters]

This appears to agree with an image and translation provided under "Vulcan language" on Memory Alpha [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan_language#Background_information):

> *Rata* ("Concept"), *Tafar* ("Discipline"), and *Tapan* ("Process") are the background names for a trinity of symbols or letters that appeared together on several Vulcan robes…

The Memory Alpha article provides this screenshot of Kuvak from *Star Trek: Enterprise*, with apparently the same symbols running down a central seam of his Vulcan robe.

[image: Kuvak in Robe]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://korsaya.org/standard-vulcan-script-%E2%80%A2-gotavlu-zukitaun/, which is the "standard" script - your chart appears to be the "calligraphic" script - they appear to be somewhat stylized versions of the letters rata, <s>shai</s> tafar, and <s>Sa</s> tapan, read from top to bottom.

(Edited: I thought originally the struck ones, but after reading the comment to the question referencing memory alpha, I compared with the chart at Korsaya, and decided that tafar and tapan were at least as good matches as shai and sa, and arguably better.)